# Display the value in prompt message using Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm newbie in using of JAVASCRIPT with PHP. I need someone to help me to solve my problem.

**Scenario:**

I have a table name **"tbldata"**.

In my database, below is my data for tbldata.

```
fldBldgName      fldPlaylist
Bldg 1            playlist1
Bldg 1            playlist2
Bldg 1            playlist3
Bldg 2            playlist4
```

I have a form where it will display all the data of **fldBldgName** with checkbox. Then when I check a checkbox of **Bldg 1** then I click a button name **"View Playlist"** it will display all the fldplaylist of bldg1 using a javascript or prompt message.

***For Summary:***

I want to display all data of *Bldg1* or other bldg in prompt message using javascript with OKAY button only. Is there a way to this? I already search to google but can't find any answer for my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, for starters, it's called "JavaScript" and not "JAVASCRIPT"...it's not an acronym.

Comment: you should talk a look at ajax

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** ways to do this.

---

**1. Do this by generating JavaScript on the server with php.** 
Small example:

**PHP (pseudo-code)**

```
$sql = // ... (your SQL query);
$list = // ... (your result objects from SQL);

// Build a html of your received items you want to show
$html = '<div id="playlists">';
foreach(listitem in list)
{
    $html .= '<div onclick="alert(\''.listitem->getBldgData().'\'">'.listitem->getTitle().'</div>';
}
$html .= '</div>';
```

This possibility is very simple but has to load everything you need before displaying it on client side. It also take very much resources if your list grows and with the list potentially the listitems data. I do not recommence to use this style.

---

**2. Do this by only generate a list of playlists and on each click on a specific playlist, load the bldg with an ajax request from the server.**

**PHP(pseudo-code) for the site**

```
$sql = // ... (your SQL query);
$list = // ... (your result objects from SQL);

// Build a html of your received items you want to show
$html = '<div id="playlists">';
foreach(listitem in list)
{
    $html .= '<div onclick="getBldgData(\''.listitem->getId().'\')">'.listitem->getTitle().'</div>';
}
$html .= '</div>';
```

**JavaScript/AJAX (pseudo-code)**

Include the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library for better ajax call handling.

```
function getBldgData(id){
   $.ajax("yourUrl/PathTo/PHPWebService", { data: id })
     .success(function(data){
        // do something with the received BldgData from the webservice (JSON)
     })
     .error(function(err){
        // message box with the error
        alert(err);
   });
};
```

**PHP(pseudo-code) for the webservice**

```
$id = $_GET['data'];
  $sql = ... // SQL Statement to get the Bldg data for this Playlist (Id);
  $BldgData = ... // received data;

  $formatBldgDataAsJSON = ... // do something to transform data which should be proceeded on client side.

  echo $formatBldgDataAsJSON;
```

---

I would recommence to use the second AJAX version. Only the needed data will be fetched from the database.

---

Sorry for the pseudo code but if I would completly write everything down in correct syntax it would take too long to write it while my lunch ;)